# Interpretação de Tags com HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou programando usando o framework Laravel e normalmente para usar o PHP dentro do HTML uso as duplas chaves

```
{{ $variavel }}
```

Já quando devo interpretar o Html dentro dessa variável eu uso

```
{!!$variavel!!}
```

Eu não entendi o porque dos pontos de exclamação, não consegui encontrar a documentação para isso.

O problema é que eu queria a função `substr()` na variável, e com isso se tiver as exclamações ou chaves ele não funciona, e se tirar fica com as tags do html que estão na string.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer dizer com o substr. Qual o resultado esperado? o que você está passando nessa variável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambas as sintaxes, como você mencionou são utilizada para exibir o conteúdo das strings dentro da sua página, a primeira escapando caracteres especiais para evitar [ataques de XSS<sup>en</sup>](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) e a segunda sintaxe permitindo isso.

> Eu não entendi o porque dos pontos de exclamação, não consegui
>   encontrar a documentação para isso.

Você pode encontrar essa explicação na [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data). Ao meu ver as exclamações são usadas para chamar a atenção, pois não é uma boa ideia utilizar a segunda forma por ter um certo risco de segurança.

```
<p>Olá {{ $nome }}</p>
<p>seu último acesso foi em {{ $data }}</p>
<p>localização {!! $local !!}
<p>tempo da sessão {{ $tempo }}
```

Answer (score 2):

A grosso modo, essas chaves no Blade são convertidas pra um `echo` mais a função `htmlspecialchars()`. Alguma coisa parecida com isso:

```
<p>Olá {{ $nome }}</p>
<p>Olá <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $nome ); ?></p>
```

Usando a segunda forma, com as exclamações, o Blade não vai escapar a `string`. O conteúdo é "impresso" diretamente, tipo:

```
<p>Olá {!! $nome !!}</p>
<p>Olá <?php echo $nome; ?></p>
```

Isso permite que sua variável possua, por exemplo, código html.

Em ambos os casos você pode utilizar qualquer função do php:

```
<p>Olá {{ substr($nome, 0, 2) }}</p>
<p>Último acesso: {!! substr(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'), 0, 10) !!}</p>
```